# What will happen in C if the passing parameter is a constant value

Tags: c

Suppose I have a main function as below:

```
void main()
{ int *p;
  p = foo(31);
  printf(“%d”, (*p)+2);
  bar(7); /* Body of function bar() not shown */ 
  printf(“%d”, (*p)+4);
}

int *foo(int x) 
{ 
  return &x;
}
```

Assuming the function bar() that compiles correctly, why the second result of the printf is **11** if the body of bar() does not write to its incoming arguments space.

More specifically, my question is why the incoming argument value of **bar()** which is **7** replaces the value **31**?

What's more, when the main function pass the value 31 into foo(), how does the value 31 passed? By register? or the compiler creates a temporary variable to pass 31? And why the incoming argument of  **foo()** and **bar()** share the same position in the memory

Comment: Okay! Two words `Undefined Behaviour`

Comment: @Sniper One word: Dyscalculia

Comment: @EOF: Why? It is UB, Sniper is right.

Comment: @Olaf You missed all of the fun.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: You're not the first to tell me. That's what I have to live with.

Comment: @Olaf You had to be there...

Comment: The proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). **note:** `main` is a function of `type int` and it returns a value. See [**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: Compile your code with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, and run it with valgrind

Comment: You're calling `foo` and `bar` with no visible declaration. For C99 and later, that's a constraint violation. For C90, it's undefined behavior, because the compiler will assume `foo` returns an `int` when in fact it returns an `int*`. Make sure your compiler at least warns you about this problem. To fix it, you can move the definitions of `foo` and `bar` above that of `main`, or you can add separate declarations. (Of course your program will still be buggy after those fixes.)

Answer (score 5):

Function parameters are its local variables. So in this function definition

```
int *foo(int x) 
{ 
  return &x;
}
```

there is returned a pointer to a local variable.

As result the program has undefined behavior.

You can imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
p = foo(31);

int *foo( /* int x */ ) 
{ 
  int x = 31;
  return &x;
}
```

The variable `x` will not be alive after exiting the function. Thus the pointer has an invalid value that is a value that does not point to an actual object. The memory allocated for the parameter of the function `foo` can be overwritten by a call of other function as for example by a call of the function `printf`..

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

and function `foo` should be declared before its usage. Otherwise the compiler can issue a message that either there is used incompatible types or it can not find the corresponding function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I should write more precisely about my question. I don't understand why the incoming argument of bar() replace the previous value of foo().

Comment: @ygyao Because the function bar or the function printf reuses the memory early used by the function foo.  So at the address where early there was the parameter x of the function foo now there can be anything that the function bar of the function printf can place there.

Comment: It seems not to be a coincident replacement. Why the incoming argument in bar(7) can replace exactly the memory address where the argument 31 stored?

Comment: With undefined behaviour, anything can happen.  Things can even seem to make sense, and/or be consistent.  Or not — anything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The function foo receives a copy of the input parameter value in its local variable x. What foo sees does not depend on whether the argument to the function is constant or not.

The vatiable x is located on the stack and is freed when foo returns. So foo returns an address to a location in the stack. Returning a pointer to a local variable is an invitation for all kinds of problems.

In this case  that same location most  probably gets reused when bar is called.